# Unexpected DV that can't be reversed?

Tags: bug

When clicking on the title of the question, I got a **weird** behavior: I had an unwanted DV. I tried to reverse it immediately with an UV. It was not registered.

I tried and edit the question within a minute (successfully) so that the DV would not be recorded or reversed. Didn't work.

Question is the one from @bradley-wilson about "referring to she/he". I was on a cellphone (latest iOS). Found nothing like that on SE network and never faced something like that.

Q: is it a known bug? Can the UV/DV be reversed?

Comment: Votes can typically be reversed within a few minutes, or after editing, most likely a bug.

Comment: Where? Android? PC? Android app creeps me out. It has a ton of issues, and the devs have sort of given up on it.

Comment: iOS on iPhone 6, with SE app

Comment: Try to reverse the downvote on PC?

Comment: Will try that as soon as I get to my PC. I'll let you know...

Comment: You all are going to make [Kasra](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/229741/kasra-rahjerdi) sad...